# Navigation Bar TintColor not working with UIColor initWithPatternImage iOS5

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, uicolor, tintcolor

I am using iOS5 and I am trying to set a custom `TintColor` for my Navigation bar.

Code : This I am using in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarImage.png"]]];
```

The Image is 320 x 44 PNG image available in my application.

When I use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

it displays the orange color but not for `PatternImage`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  an UINavigationBar category to set background image.

```
#import "UINavigationBar+Background.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (Background)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarImage.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks fannheyward, Actually there is even a simpler way to get this done. I just figured it out.
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

This works perfectly for any sort of custom made image. No need to add a Category.

Comment: @ShriniketSarkar My mistake. Why don't you use `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` directly?